# Separating lists in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For something like

`<div init="friends = [{name: 'John'}, {name: 'Maury'}]"></div>`,

Having code like `{{friend.name}}` prints out the entire array. But what I would like to do is assign one portion of the array to each div. So, something like this.

`<div init="friends = [{name: 'John}]">Random Stuff Here</div>
<div id="randomdiv"></div>`

`<div init="friends = [{name: 'Maury'}]">More Random Stuff Here</div>`

That way each div is given its own ID. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: first of all ask properly. write proper directives, its not **init** its **ng-init**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use `ng-init` it seems that you want to have a controller/viewmodel that has the friends array and loop over that with `ng-repeat`

```
this.fiends = [{name: "John"}, {name: "Maury"}];

<div ng-repeat="friend in ctrl.friends">
  {{friend.name}}
</div>
```